# ReactJS: ReferenceError: submitClick is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have gone through the solutions provided regarding this problem but i still have the problem.

This is my simple code

```
<button onClick={submitClick} id="SubmitBtn">Request Invite</button>
```

then in the index.js file i have this function: which is meant to execute onClick on the submit button.

```
function submitClick() {

  window.alert("JEBE");

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please `bind` the function in the `constructor`

```js
        class App extends React.Component {
         
           constructor(props){
                  super(props);
                  this.state={
                   value:""
                  }
                   this.submitClick = this.submitClick.bind(this);
                   this.change = this.change.bind(this);
               }
               change(e){
                 this.setState({
                  value : e.target.value
                 });
               }
               submitClick(){
              alert(this.state.value);
            }
          render() {
            return <div>
              <form>
              Email <input id="MainEmail" type="email" 
                           placeholder ="Enter your email"
                           onChange={this.change}
                           /> 
                     <button onClick={this.submitClick} 
                              id="SubmitBtn">Request Invite
                              </button>
              </form>
              <br/><br/>
            </div>;
          }
        }


        ReactDOM.render(
          <App />,
          document.getElementById('container')
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I still get this error message: Failed to compile. I have the constructor in the .js file I hope that's how I should implement it?

Comment: Please share ur entire component so that would be easy to address problem.

Comment: `import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'

const IndexPage = () => (
<div>

  <div className="Hero">
    <div className="HeroGroup">
      <h1>My first firesbase + react app</h1>
      <p>Let's explore the best way to use these tools</p>
      <div className="form">
      <input id="MainEmail" type="email" placeholder ="Enter your email"/>
      <button onClick={this.submitClick} id="SubmitBtn">Request Invite</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)

export default IndexPage`

Comment: thanks for helping out, but i still get this error message. **TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```jsx
<button onClick={this.submitClick} id="SubmitBtn">Request Invite</button>
```

Comment: i just tried this and i get this error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitClick' of undefined

Comment: can you please post your entire ReactJS class?

Comment: and ```this.submitClick = this.submitClick.bind(this);```